# Way to reflect count in Journey builder after factoring the Exclusion Script

Tags: marketing-cloud

this is a simplified journey which leveraging on exclusion script to filter customers meant to be excluded (e.g. to be updated daily). Yes, it has achieved the purpose to filter excluded customers by checking the send report, but it would be great that the count in the email activity - journey builder factoring in the excluded customers (in this case total of 3 customers - 1 excluded customer = 2 customers). Is there anyone knows if this is doable?

[image: Simple Journey]
[image: Exclusion Script]

Comment: you can't change the canvas counts

Comment: How about forgetting exclusion scripts? They obfuscate journey logic. Add your exclusion Data Extension to Contact Builder's Data Designer and add a contact filter to your entry criteria and exit criteria for the Journey.

Comment: In the journey, there could be reminder emails, hence, contact filter at the entry criteria is applicable only for the first email send out. For the subsequent reminder emails which comes at few days later and some customers could be excluded when latest data refresh, contact filter might not able to work. Yeah, exit criteria is working. Thanks so much.